# Add asterisk after labels in enumerate

Tags: spacing, enumerate

I would like to add an asterisk after certain labels in the enumerate environment. So for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Kuttel
    \item* Daddeldu
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

but without the space between 2. und *.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newenvironment{modenumerate}
  {\enumerate\setupmodenumerate}
  {\endenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{##1\ifmoditem\rlap{\mesymbol}\fi\enspace}%
    \global\moditemfalse}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{modenumerate}
\item uno
\item due
\moditem{*} tre
\item\label{four} quattro
\moditem{*}[\hfill\ref{four}.] quattro
\end{modenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For an `enumitem` complying version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{modenumerate}[1][]
  {\enumerate[#1]\setupmodenumerate}
  {\endenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{##1\ifmoditem\rlap{\mesymbol}\fi\enspace}%
    \global\moditemfalse}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{modenumerate}
\item uno
\item due
\moditem{*} tre
\item\label{four} quattro
\moditem{*}[\hfill\ref{four}.] quattro
\end{modenumerate}

Some text.

\begin{modenumerate}[resume]
\item cinque
\item sei
\moditem{*} sette
\item\label{eight} otto
\moditem{*}[\hfill\ref{eight}.] otto
\end{modenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `resume` option not working with this type of list? Could this be fixed?

Comment: @mavzolej There is no `resume` if you don't load `enumitem`. Please, open a new question showing the issue you have.

Comment: Interesting. I do have the package `enumitem` included in the preamble, and it does work for the usual `enumerate` environment but not for this new one.

Comment: @mavzolej Now I see. Added the example.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item One

\item Two

\item $\!\!\!\!{^*}$ Three

\item Four

\end{enumerate}
```

does the trick! Easy.

`\!` moves the next text a tad to the left, use as many or few as to your preference.

Comment: Or you can use `\hspace{-xpt}` where x is a number. Which doesn't require math mode.

Comment: I like this better: `$\mathllap{{}^*\,\,}$`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to tailor your labels like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[1. ] Kuttel
    \item[2.*] Daddeldu
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Notice the extra space after the 1. in order to align 1 and 2 vertically.

Beware: this solution is pureley an aesthetic one for single levels enumerations.  I don't know what will become of the nested items...

It is very simple but not scalable.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following solution that puts stars before the labels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A first item
  \bgroup
  \let\oldenum\labelenumi
  \renewcommand\labelenumi{*\oldenum}
  \item A starred item
  \egroup
\item A third item
  \bgroup
  \let\oldenum\labelenumi
  \renewcommand\labelenumi{*\oldenum}
  \item Another starred item
  \egroup
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Changing `\renewcommand\labelenumi{*\oldenum}` to `\renewcommand\labelenumi{\oldenum *}` messes up the alignment of the numbers.

I couldn't get this to work as a macro though.

Answer (score -1):

one can use "description" instead of "enumerate"

```
\begin{description}
\item $1.^{*}$   Kuttel
    \item $2.^{*}$ Daddeldu
\end{description}
```

Comment: While this is a possible solution it might get tedious to use this for each `\item` line and the alignment of the description text is lost!