# How to typeset enumerations with asterisk?

Tags: enumerate

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item See below
  \item [2\textsuperscript{*}.] This isn't right. Or?
  \item [3*.] This neither.
  \item [4.*] Even worse.
  \item See above
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

*Shouldn't instead both the dot and the asterisk be directly at the number?*

(I found this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298893/36836 but I am not familiar with the `\up` command. Is it just equivalent with `\textsuperscript`?)

**Edit**

I agree that the the title of a question marked as duplicate ([Add asterisk after labels in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21004/add-asterisk-after-labels-in-enumerate)) can be read to ask the same question. However my question added in the body of the question points to a more particular request that seems neither in the other question nor in any of the answer given to that question. I could change the title of my question slightly but that would render some of the answers given to my question look strange. So I leave it with this edit.

**Edit 2**

Based on a comment ([How to typeset enumerations with asterisk?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314477/how-to-typeset-enumerations-with-asterisk#comment767133_314480)) I prefer as a solution:

```
\newcommand{\aster}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}
```

Comment: Either way is typographically awful, and also very bad from the programming point of view. Have you considered `1)` and `2*)` rather than `1.` and `2*.` or `2.*` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the asterisk over the top of the dot, with no spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\aster}{%
    \newlength{\l@aster}%
    \settowidth{\l@aster}{*}%
    *\hspace{-\l@aster}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item See below.
  \item [2\textsuperscript{*}.] This isn't right. Or?
  \item [3*.] This neither.
  \item [4.*] Even worse.
  \item [5\aster{}.] How about this?


\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: asterisk over dot]

I've called the new asterisk command `\aster` because I couldn't immediately think of anywhere else that's used.  I suggest you pick your own name, pairing the new length `\l@aster` with it.

Personally I'd go for a different version (`\item[*6.]`):

[image: my choice]

Comment: why not use `\makebox[0pt]{*}`here instead?

Comment: @runartrollet because I didn't think of it! :)

Comment: IMHO option 5 is the worst, the two symbols souldn't be atop each other. Also, the space after the star is now too short because the star protrudes to the right of the dot.

Comment: @yo'.  I'm inclined to agree with you, but if it's what the OP wants...  I'd go for `\item[*5.]` personally.  The manual numbering bugs me too.

Comment: @ChrisH The manual numbering is solvable of course (see my answer).

Comment: @runartrollet The `\makebox[0pt]{*}` seems not to work in the optional argument of an enumerate environment.

Comment: @Daniel You have to brace it, if it is inside an optional argument: `\item[5{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}]`

Answer (score 2):

From your information I gather that you are trying to have some items stand out using stars, and you want it typeset directly above the dot. There are numerous ways to do this. Here I made a function, which do the counting for you. You could improve this using the `enumitem` package, so you don't need to write `[\printnum]` for every item. That all depends on how often you will need to do a list like this in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{itemC}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printNum}{s}{%
    \stepcounter{itemC}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {%
        %Do Starred%
        \theitemC.\makebox[0pt]{*}%
    }{%
        %Do Unstarred%
        \theitemC.%
    }%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item [\printNum]  See below
  \item [\printNum*] This isn't right. Or?
  \item [\printNum*] This neither.
  \item [\printNum*] Even worse.
  \item [\printNum] See above
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seem to reach the same result as http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314480/36836. So my choice of answer is a bit arbitrary. I already loaded the `calc` package in my document which probably many do. So I went with that answer.

Comment: I like the way you've fixed the numbering, I think I prefer your answer to mine.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally *never* use any of `1.*` or `1*.` or `1{* above .}`, all of them just look wrong. I would stick to the `1)` and `1*)` style. Also, I think you shouldn't have to number the list manually, so I coded a `\staritem` for you:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*)}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\staritem{\@noitemargtrue\@item[\arabic{enumi}*)]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{enumerate}

\item Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
 foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.

\staritem Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
 bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\item Baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz
 baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz.

\end{enumerate}
Some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I kind of have to use the `1*.` version because I am extending a numbering from a quote which uses `1.`. That is also why manual numbering is okay in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yet not sure to have fully understood, but loading the `enumitem` package, this  gives an automatic label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, makebox}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label =\arabic*\rlap{\textsuperscript*}\protect\makebox*{\textsuperscript*}{.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}%
\item Is this OK? 1
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But that wasn't my question. I guess that's my fault in formulating it.

Comment: @Daniel: I've changed my answer. Is it more like what you want?